# Mapeamento responsivo de imagem

Tags: layout-responsivo

Fiz o mapeamento da imagem como no exemplo abaixo, porém não funciona para dispositivos móveis, fica totalmente desconfigurado, qual a solução?

```
<img src="CAMINHO DA IMAGEM_01" alt="TEXTO ALTERNATIVO DA IMAGEM" usemap="#map01" />
<map name="map01" id="map01">
        <area shape="FORMA DO MAPA" coords="CORDENADAS" href="LINK" alt="TEXTO ALTERNATIVO" title="TITULO DO SEULINK" />
        <area shape="FORMA DO MAPA" coords="CORDENADAS" href="LINK" alt="TEXTO ALTERNATIVO" title="TITULO DO SEULINK" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o plugin [Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin by Matt Stow](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps) (jQuery requerido).

**Como funciona?**

Não coloque os atributos `width` ou `height` na imagem. Faça isso pelo CSS com imagem responsiva:

```
img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Carregue o plugin (código abaixo) e chame:

```
$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
```

**Veja funcionando:**

A metade direita da imagem é LINK1, e a da esquerda é LINK2.

```js
/*
* rwdImageMaps jQuery plugin v1.6
*
* Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by recalculating the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and window.resize
*
* Copyright (c) 2016 Matt Stow
* https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps
* http://mattstow.com
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/
;(function(a){a.fn.rwdImageMaps=function(){var c=this;var b=function(){c.each(function(){if(typeof(a(this).attr("usemap"))=="undefined"){return}var e=this,d=a(e);a("<img />").on('load',function(){var g="width",m="height",n=d.attr(g),j=d.attr(m);if(!n||!j){var o=new Image();o.src=d.attr("src");if(!n){n=o.width}if(!j){j=o.height}}var f=d.width()/100,k=d.height()/100,i=d.attr("usemap").replace("#",""),l="coords";a('map[name="'+i+'"]').find("area").each(function(){var r=a(this);if(!r.data(l)){r.data(l,r.attr(l))}var q=r.data(l).split(","),p=new Array(q.length);for(var h=0;h<p.length;++h){if(h%2===0){p[h]=parseInt(((q[h]/n)*100)*f)}else{p[h]=parseInt(((q[h]/j)*100)*k)}}r.attr(l,p.toString())})}).attr("src",d.attr("src"))})};a(window).resize(b).trigger("resize");return this}})(jQuery);
$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
```

```css
img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="TEXTO ALTERNATIVO DA IMAGEM" usemap="#map01" />
<map name="map01" id="map01">
   <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,315,354" href="LINK1" alt="TEXTO ALTERNATIVO1" title="TITULO DO SEULINK1" />
   <area shape="rect" coords="316,0,630,354" href="LINK2" alt="TEXTO ALTERNATIVO1" title="TITULO DO SEULINK2" />
</map>
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, mas não tenho o conhecimento técnico pra implementar os códigos, entendo o básico de html, quando envolve java script fico perdido.

Comment: @Aprendiz No final do <body> vc coloca <script> código </script>, onde "código" é todo o código JavaScript da resposta. Apenas isso.