# Mapeamento html de imagem que funcione no celular

Tags: html, imagem, layout-responsivo

Olá! Eu tenho um site wordpress com o tema BeTheme instalado. Ele possui slides, entre outras funcionalidades.
Eu estou fazendo o mapeamento de uma imagem e para isso usei o Gimp. Funcionou quase perfeitamente, a não ser pelo fato que as coordenadas estão erradas, e as áreas clicáveis ficaram fora de posição em relação a imagem.
Esse é um problema que ainda não consegui resolver, mas tem outra coisa. Quando o site é acessado pelo celular, o mapeamento não funciona.

Então, tenho essas duas questões para resolver, e espero conseguir a ajuda de vocês:
1- por que as coordenadas "não batem"?
2- como tornar o mapeamento da imagem responsivo?

Esta é a página em questão: http://montanhasmagicas.com.br/guia-para-montanha/

Abaixo está o código que coloquei nessa página:

#### Aqui nesta seção você encontrarà as coordenadas dos principais pontos turìsticos da cidade.

Desde já agradeço qualquer colaboração dos membros.

Comment: Seria importante você colocar seu código html/css atual.

Comment: 1- As coordenadas não batem porque vc precisa passar as coordenadas corretamente. Se você usou um software que fez isso e o resultado foi incorreto, desinstale-o porque não serve. 2- Mapeamento responsivo você pode usar este plugin: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/265824/8063

Answer (score 1):

Este site (https://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/) gera o código html/css responsivo que será necessário para seu mapa.

Insira a imagem de seu mapa lá (http://montanhasmagicas.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Mapa-Andrel%C3%A2ndia.png) e clique em "GO". 
A imagem aparecerá e você poderá arrastar o bloco do primeiro link (à esquerda) e configurar. 
Em seguida, clique em "ADD LINK" e repita o processo para os demais links.

No rodapé da página aparecerá o código HTML/CSS necessário para você colocar na sua página.

Ex:

```
<a href="" title="xxxx" style="position: absolute; left: 38.37%; top: 16.93%; width: 9.69%; height: 10.19%; z-index: 1;"></a>
```

Sugiro também que permita que a imagem seja ampliada quando num celular, pois o mapa ficará ilegível em telas pequenas. Mas com esse código responsivo, os links permanecerá no lugar correto, independente do tamanho da imagem.